# FTP file manager AS wordpress site

Tags: ftp, filesystem, file-manager

Ok, maybe it a far fetch question, and a question about depersonalisation of something into something else, but let try.

One on my client want a easy file bin for his client to go get the public HR file for publicity. The main company have the HR pdf and some newspaper or local advertising need it. Instead of sending those file by email, CD or free FTP like "senduit.com" a site will be created.

A bunch of folder, with a bunch of file. Let say

**Winter 2010 AD**

- french ad 8.5 x 11
- english ad 8.5 x 11

**Summer 2011 AD**

- french poster
- English poster

and so on, understand the concept ?

So what will be the best plugin set or system for that... wordpress seem fit to that, but it's sont OUT OF THE BOX as this..

system should be secure, but's that just adding a password page.. that simple...

What will be your solution ?

Comment: Does it have to be a WordPress solution? I would ask on [the Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) for an existing file sharing service that gives you flexibility in branding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [WP-Filebase](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/) would be a suitable plugin for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this plugin too [Easy FTP Upload](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-ftp-upload/) This has simple code you can use it for ftp upload of files.  The code is also so simple and can be customised.  Hope this helps some one.